# How do I play CD games with ubuntu?

Tags: wine, games

I have got 3 games that I really want to play on ubuntu, but I don't know how to get them working.

So I recently found three games on CDs that I wanna play, when I put the disc in the cd-rom a cd mark appears in the launcher tab, I click on it and then the home folder appears with all the folders and items that are in the cd. When I right click on setup.exe

(I'm aware that I can open games by going into permissions in properties and allowing executing file as a program, but it says "Sorry, could not change the permissions of "Setup.exe": Error setting permissions: Read-only file system")

and open it with Wine Windows Program Loader, nothing happens.

If it helps the games that I'm trying to install are "Command & Conquer Red alert 2", "City Life" and "Theme Hospital".

I'm aware of terminal as well but I don't know how to use it very well... 
Please help.

Comment: You can use PlayonLinux for playing games on Ubuntu

Comment: I have it installed, and I have tried it as well. unfortunately it isn't listed there and neither does it work when I click on "install a non listed program".

Comment: Like I said nothing happenes when I try opening it with wine.

Comment: You seem to be doing everything the right way so it may be a problem with the version of wine you are running. Try installing the latest wine version by typing 'sudo apt-get install wine1.7' in the terminal and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually to make games work on wine you search for each game on winehq (and other websites); just type in the name of the game and "wine". for example: *"command and conquer red alert 2 wine"*

You do that because usually you should see instructions for some extra things that you have to do to wine to make the game work. mostly through "winetricks"

anyways I've done some searching for you for red alert.
*I love this game ;)*

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RedAlert2

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=252

...search on and good luck